# Add header in Nginx ONLY when retry

Tags: nginx

We configured nginx to retry requests to another server in the upstream upon timeout and error via:

```
proxy_next_upstream http_503 timeout;
proxy_next_upstream_tries 2;
```

But we'd like the second server to be aware that this is actually a retry request.

We know how to add headers to the request (add_header), but we don't know how to add some marker that its a retry.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no variable in NGINX for upstream retries count.: [Alphabetical index of variables](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html)

But you can use an alternative solution to track retry requests, such as append `$upstream_status` or `$upstream_addr` or `$upstream_status` in your NGINX load balancer.